# Frame labels & function parameters

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Is it possible to change a frame label within a gotoAndStop('label') with the parameters in a function?

I'm playing around with updating code as I learn more and more techniques, and at the moment the code is a basic click-a-button to select the object shape, and on press the button disappears:

```
// Change the object into a circle.
circle_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(){changeShape_fun(circle_btn,circle);});

// Change the object into a square.
square_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(){changeShape_fun(square_btn,square);});

// Change the object into a star.
star_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(){changeShape_fun(star_btn,star);});

function changeShape_fun(shape_btn,frame){
shape_btn.visible = false;
main_mc.gotoAndStop('frame');
}
```

However I can't/don't seem to know how to change a frame label through function parameters, or if what I'm trying to do is even possible.

Also to note, while I'm all ears for any more efficient ways of doing what I'm trying to do, I would still like to know how/if you can change frame labels through function parmeters.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, but you're trying to go to a frame called 'frame' and not the string contained within the **frame** variable. Try this instead:

```
// Change the object into a circle.
circle_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(event:MouseEvent){changeShape_fun(circle_btn, 'circle');});

// Change the object into a square.
square_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(event:MouseEvent){changeShape_fun(square_btn, 'square');});

// Change the object into a star.
star_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(event:MouseEvent){changeShape_fun(star_btn, 'star');});

function changeShape_fun(shape_btn,frame){
    shape_btn.visible = false;
    main_mc.gotoAndStop(frame);
}
```

This will go to a frame within **main_mc** called 'circle' when you click the circle or 'square' if you click the square, etc.